# jQuery - slideDown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a slideDown menu, i have navigation in html and ul with 4 elements. When im clicking image of menu it slied down but after that shows error in console

```
Cannot read property 'display' of undefined
```

Here's the code:

```
function menu() {
        var ul = $(".ul_menu");
        $(".slide_down_menu").on("click", function() {
            ul.slideDown(400);
        });

        $(document).on("click", function() {
            if (ul.css('display') == 'block') {
                ul.slideUp(400);
            }
        });

    }
```

HTML

```
<nav class="mobile">
                <button type="button" class="slide_down_menu"><img src="gallery/menu.png"></button>
                <ul class="ul_menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#main_page" title="">O nas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#location" title="">Lokalizacja</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#gallery" title="">Galeria</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact" title="">Kontakt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Your HTML ??. Always post the minimum code required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry, i edited, my menu slide Down but not turns back. I did code which is working but after slideDown it automaticlly slideUp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the dropdown using below code and use `e.stopPropogation()` to prevent clicks within the dropdown.

```js
$(function() {
  var ul = $(".ul_menu");

  $(document).click(function() {
    ul.slideUp(400);
  });

  $(".slide_down_menu").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ul.slideToggle(400);
  });

});
```

```css
.ul_menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="mobile">
  <button type="button" class="slide_down_menu"><img src="gallery/menu.png"></button>
  <ul class="ul_menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#main_page" title="">O nas</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#location" title="">Lokalizacja</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#gallery" title="">Galeria</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact" title="">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yup, that's exacly what i was looking for, many thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Are you sure call `menu()` function? Its seem not problem in your code.
```

```js
function menu() {
    var ul = $(".ul_menu");
    $(".slide_down_menu").on("click", function() {
        $(ul).slideDown(400); 
    });

    $(document).on("click", function(e) { 
    if(!($(e.target).hasClass(".slide_down_menu")||($(e.target).closest(".slide_down_menu").length))){
        if (ul.css('display') == 'block') {
            $(ul).slideUp(400);
        }}
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  menu();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="mobile">
                <button type="button" class="slide_down_menu"><img src="gallery/menu.png"></button>
                <ul class="ul_menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#main_page" title="">O nas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#location" title="">Lokalizacja</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#gallery" title="">Galeria</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact" title="">Kontakt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: That code is working, errors gone don't know why, it's strange. But next problem that i had before is when iclick menu icon it slies down and automaticlly slies up, how can i stop this ??

Comment: when click on `$(".slide_down_menu")` , actually  you are clicked on document , you must check if clicked element is your button return ;

Comment: `  if(!$(evt.target).is("$(".slide_down_menu")))
          return;`